# Recovery and Download mode on a device

Tags: recovery-mode

On a dated device, Sony Xperia Tipo, I can not get the recovery mode. Yet I remember that I used it some years ago, but also with `adb reboot recovery` it continues to start in normal mode. I have just unlocked the bootloader, and before of that I rooted the device using the Kingroot app. Possible that has this app wiped the recovery partition?

Also I can not find references to start in download mode.

Comment: As you mentioned that the device didn't boot to recovery, it is most probable that the recovery partition has been wiped off. Have you tried reflashing the recovery image?

Comment: @bikalpa Can you explain me the reason why it could have been wiped off? Moreover I have no idea where I can get the original recovery, I had only seen the firmware (I guess the original Sony) on xda ( https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-j-e/general/ftf-xperia-ftf-firmwares-collection-t2001567). Can you tell me where I can find it, please?

Comment: Can't you just reflash custom recovery like TWRP to get into recovery mode? As far as the reason is concerned, I have no idea, but maybe unlocking bootloader wiped it off.

Comment: Try rebooting from terminal within the phone (use terminal emulator) ,first ask for root permission using the su  command then type reboot recovery see if it works (adb reboot recovery might not work on some OEM android builds due to restrictions)

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf I do not currently have the root. I had uninstalled Kingroot and ran factory reset. I have only the bootloader unlocked. Maybe is the unlocked downloader the reason of the lacking of recovery mode (i.e. the recovery partition *is still in memory*, but the bootloader doesn't recognize the combination volume+power so it uses ordinary boot)?

Comment: @bikalpa I would like the original Sony recovery. The xda firmware I mentioned is the original one in your opinion? And is the recovery partition included in the firmware?